# How to create this object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, blend-files

anyone know how to create this object using Blender. I tried several times but it's too hard for me. Please help me

[image]

**Edit:**

Thanks, [moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/288064/35559)! I watched [your tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDF3ewabogU). It's really helpful. Thank you very much to share your experience.

[image]

Comment: Which object exactly?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create this pattern:

[image]

Repeat it on X and Z with 2 *Array* modifiers:

[image]

Make it rotate with a *Simple Deform* modifier in *Bend* mode, on Z:

[image]

Deform it with a *Mesh Deform* modifier and a cube that you rotate and twist:

[image]

Comment: Thank you brother. But I'm new for blender. Can you make short tutorial. I think it's helpful to everyone. I searched about this YouTube but I didn't find correct tutorial.

Comment: Yes I can make one about this object on YT

Comment: Thank you again. I'm waiting for tutorial.

Comment: So, the tutorial is here in french, feel free to ask questions if you don't understand some points: https://youtu.be/cDF3ewabogU

Comment: @moonboots .. just a ping to replace OP's deleted 'Thanks' answer, which has been edited into his post. (Nice video, BTW)

Comment: @Robin Betts, ok thanks  ;)  ..............

Comment: Hello brother, I made it. Thanks for your tutorial. Here you can see and comment something https://www.instagram.com/p/Cpt3JoVhgn5/?igshid=YmMyMTA2M2Y=

Comment: Thanks @Chamod Jayashanka, well done, I don't have any Instaram account though  ;)

Comment: It's okay. I uploaded it my Google Drive. check it out here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eHwI8E2-ho2HlH4vUft2FS08nIqz52fC?usp=share_link